# Administrator user types in windows client OS and server OS are different?

Tags: windows

I created an administrator user, adminWin10 in Win 10 OS and adminWin2012 in Win server 2012 R2.

When I create a new folder in c:\program files(x86) in Win 10, I get following warning message.

[image]

I do the same operation in Win 2012 Server R2, I don't get warning message. Folder created.

Are administrator user types in windows client OS and server OS are different?

Comment: What happened when you clicked 'Continue'?

Comment: Folder created.

Comment: Ok so essentially its a security prompt, you're not prevented from doing anything.

Try this, type 'UAC' into the Windows Start menu.
Click "Change User Account Control settings."
Move the slider down to "Never Notify."
Click OK and then restart the computer.

Now try creating a folder in c:\program files(x86) again and see if that prompt occurs.